# How to make my problem solved?

Tags: discussion, support

I always search before asking which is my last resort. I've literally searched several hours upon this problem and all the solutions are irrelevant and/or not applicable.

What can I do to get this solved quick? I'm really annoyed, fed up, getting behind with several projects.

In case you can help please do [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/147723/device-descriptor-read-64-error-110-when-connecting-usb-keyboard)

Comment: I don't get what you're asking. It sounds like you're asking someone to help with your other question. If so, that is not what meta is for.

Comment: Why is this site/community mostly answering questions already answered on internet but reluctant to answer problems not solved yet?

Comment: Where are you getting that idea from?

Comment: @Patrick lots of experience not only from unix but all stack sites

Answer (score 6):

First of all, we do not "mostly answer questions already answered on internet", quite the opposite in fact. We, like all SE sites get annoyed when you ask questions whose answer is easily found elsewhere. Anyway, if your question has not been answered, that means a combination of the following things must be true:

1. Your question is not very clear.

   Given the number of comments you have received, this is likely true here. For example, while you have given quite a bit of information you have not actually told us the make and model of your keyboard. You also further confuse the issue by mentioning Android, what does Android have to do with it?
2. The question has not been seen by enough people.

   Well, wait a while. You posted this meta question less than 24 hours after posting your question. It has now been 3 days, questions are not always answered immediately. You might hare to wait a few days or weeks before whoever can help you actually reads it. Be patient.
3. The people who have seen it simply don't know the answer.

   Sorry, we are not omniscient. This is not done to spite you, it is simply the way things are. Not all questions can be answered by the members of this community, sometimes we just don't know.

Comment: I added all info in comments to question and made it more condensed.

Answer (score 4):

In theory you could [offer a bounty](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties), but the question isn't old enough and you don't have enough reputation to offer for it. It hasn't been that long, I'd just wait and hope somebody who sees it has an idea.

Comment: I'm really worried because it has had only about 2 views in about 14 hours

Comment: 2 views would be quite low, this meta post has had more than that. I see 38 views on your original post

Comment: I'm sorry I meant in 24 hours not 12.I tend to confuse numbers.

Answer (score 4):

The fact that there are so many comments and no answers is a clear indication that the question itself is insufficiently detailed and does not have enough information for anyone to be able to proffer a substantive answer.

If you find your question is only generating comments requesting more information or clarification, you are encouraged to edit it (repeatedly, if necessary) to improve its clarity, detail and overall quality.

Good questions generate answers commensurate in quality (and often in quantity as well).

Comment: I added all the info in comments and then condensed the whole question